# I've thousands of articles and i want to set a category for them via a db query

Tags: database, wordpress, categories, bulk

Since i've thousands of articles the bulk edit is impossible. It will require too much time and with 999 articles a time WordPress will already crash.

So i thought about using a simple db query but i'm not sure how to build it.

How can i set a specific category for every post containing a specific word?

For example i want to put into the "business" category every article containing the "business" word.

What kind of query should i use?

I tried something i found here but without any success. The answer are always not clear or suggesting to use the bulk edit function that is something i can't use.

Comment: Where exactly should the word we are looking for be? The content (editor), the title, any custom fields?

Comment: Thank you for you answer George. The word should be inside the content and/or the title.

Comment: A SQL query solution to your problem is possible, but making it as robust as @GeorgeP's solution takes some work. I can do it but only if you need it.

Comment: It would be great. I was originally thinking about it instead of making use of PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WP CLI commands is the most performant way of doing this: it's high performant, and uses WordPress functions (mentioned by [GeorgeP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76449950/ive-thousands-of-articles-and-i-want-to-set-a-category-for-them-via-a-db-query/76457578#comment134809192_76450049)).

Use `wp post list` to get the list of posts, and then `wp post term add` to set the term on the posts.

Here's a Bash script I found that may work (untested):

```bash
for post in $(wp post list --s=business --format=ids)
do
wp post term add $post category 'category_name'
done
```

Source:
https://www.presslabs.com/code/wp-cli-guide-wp-term/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WP_Query` to retrieve posts based on your criteria and then you can use the `wp_set_post_categories()` to set the category you want:

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('business');

$args = array(
    's' => 'business',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category__not_in' => array($category_id),
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        wp_set_post_categories(get_the_ID(), array($category_id));
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

In the above query, the 's' parameter is used to specify the search term . It searches for the exact word "business" in  the post title, post content, and post excerpt.

It won't match variations of the word or partial matches. If you also want the word "businesses" or "businessman," then you can use the 's' parameter with wildcards:

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'business*',
    // Rest of the arguments...
);
```

Make sure you only run the above query once, so don't leave it inside a `functions.php` file otherwise it will be executed every time you load a page.

Depending on your server's specs, it might timeout if you have many thousands of matched posts. Just run the query again and it will complete, since it will skip the posts from previous runs (`'category__not_in'`).

Comment: If you put `set_time_limit(10);` or something like that inside the `->have_posts()` loop you may be able to beat the timeout problem.

Comment: @O.Jones is right. Another approach would be to add a LIMIT on the query, instead of `'posts_per_page' => -1`,, and then run it a couple of times till all posts are done. It will process your matched posts in chunks.

Comment: What about something that can be run into MySQL? Shouldn't be better?

Comment: @LucaSpinelli Define `better`. This is something you will do just once, if it's performance you are worried about. The above solution is solid and robust. Making use of WordPress default functions is the best practice. You can always opt to use the $wpdb object instead of direct SQL queries.

Comment: Let's say that the hosting is quite weak and with thousands i literally mean thousands of articles so i feel using a db query more efficient and fast instead of running PHP multiple times on multiple websites.